# how to convert mysql array into php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

i have a array like below:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [city_name] => Hyderabad ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [city_name] => Visakhapatnam )
        [and so on..] => and so on...
      )
```

this array is return by this block of code:::

```
 $query = "select city_name from city";
 $result = $CI->Dbmodel->customQueryResult($query);
 print_r(array_values($result));
```

and i would like to convert the above array to:

```
array('Hyderabad','Visakhapatnam','and so on..')
```

do php provide any built-in-function?

how can i do this?.. any help or suggestion would be a great help..thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the code that gets you the array you already have

Comment: Are you using a framework? The sign will be to map the array to convert objects into arrays...

Comment: @AllanStepps Sir.. yes.. codeigniter...

Comment: A simple `foreach` ? `$city = array();
    foreach($yourobj as $obj)
    {
     $city[]=$obj->city_name;
    }`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360859/get-array-of-column-values-in-codeigniter

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thanks sir..your comment does this...works like charms.. thank you very much sir..

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$query = "select city_name from city";
$result = $CI->Dbmodel->customQueryResult($query)->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify your model use this code

```
$reslt = array();
    foreach($result_array as $value){
        $reslt[] = $value->city_name;
    }
```

or use `result_array()` function.